# Не отображаются графики plotly на странице GitHub

Tags: github, график, plotly

Залил репозиторий с графиками plotly, которые используют JavaScript. При отображении в Juputer Notebook все отлично. На гите графиков нет. Есть ли какой способ отобразить их? Понятно, что интерактивность пропадет, важно увидеть сам график, оси, подписи, в общем самое необходимое.

[ссылка на проект](https://github.com/IamSVP94/Python-for-data-analysis-course/blob/master/2week/exam.ipynb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустил рендер в ноутбуке, теперь в nbviewer работает

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='notebook'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fig = go.Figure(...)
fig.show("png")
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).